# Time.deltaTime not working as desired

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've written following code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ObstacleSpawn : MonoBehaviour {

    public PlayerScript pScript;
    public ObstacleScript oScript;

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject obstacle;

    public float randomSpawnMin;
    public float randomSpawnMax;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", 2F, Random.Range (randomSpawnMin, randomSpawnMax));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () { 

    }

    void Spawn() {
        if (pScript.isRight == true && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3 (0.05F, (4F + pScript.playerDimensionY + oScript.obstacleDimensionY) * Time.deltaTime, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        } else if (pScript.isRight == false && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3 (-0.05F, (4F + pScript.playerDimensionY + oScript.obstacleDimensionY) * Time.deltaTime, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

In my void Spawn() I spawn an item called obstacle, which should be instantiated a desired amount away from my player in seconds. (Etc. it should be 2 seconds away before hitting the player, or 1 seconds and so on. What you can see in my void is me Instantiating the obstacle at the position of the player + an amount I measured, then multiplied by Time.deltaTime. However my distance do not change, wether I change my value multiplied with Time.deltaTime or not. The distance between my objects is always 0.02 seconds.

How do I work around this to customize my time interval?

EDIT - To make some clarification this is 2D, and I also will show this example to create some understanding.
I tried removing the multiplying of Time.deltaTime aswell, as the programs movement does run in deltaTime anyways:

```
void Spawn() {
        if (pScript.isRight == true && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3 (0.05F, (4F + pScript.playerDimensionY + oScript.obstacleDimensionY), 0), Quaternion.identity);
        } else if (pScript.isRight == false && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3 (-0.05F, (4F + pScript.playerDimensionY + oScript.obstacleDimensionY), 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

Shown code gives me an interval of 0.58 seconds, which is at least an interval. With this logic I believed this code should provide a 1.16 interval(twice the interval):

```
void Spawn() {
        if (pScript.isRight == true && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3 (0.05F, (8F + pScript.playerDimensionY + oScript.obstacleDimensionY), 0), Quaternion.identity);
        } else if (pScript.isRight == false && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3 (-0.05F, (8F + pScript.playerDimensionY + oScript.obstacleDimensionY), 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

This however gives the result of 0.92 interval, not 1.16 - which is where I really get confused.

EDIT FOR CONTEXT:

[image]

The red obstacle always moves down to hit the player, but I need it to spawn at an adjustable time away (1 seconds away, 0.5 seconds away etc.).

Comment: Time.deltaTime can only be used in Update().  your code is totally meaningless and won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usage of Time.deltaTime makes sense in Update methods only. Make sure you're calling your Spawn() method from Update() or LateUpdate().
To be more specific, deltaTime property stores the exact amount of time since the last update call.
Anyway, I'm not sure why would you want to make that distance dependent on the framerate. If you know the speed of your player, you should make his movement time-dependent, but not distance calculation.
In order to spawn objects with an inverval I suggest using a coroutine. Something like that:

```
private IEnumerator CoSpawn()
    {
        while (true)//you can put here any stop condition, otherwise this coroutine will run while gameObject exists and its not stopped by StopCoroutine()
        {
            //actual Spawn() call that will instantiate a new obstacle

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0, randomSpawnMax) + 2f); //pause for [2-(2+randomSpawnMax)] interval
        }
    }
```

You can start this coroutine using StartCoroutine() in Start() method instead of InvokeRepeating().

**Update:**
Ok, if you want to calculate right distance of the obstacle, then I assume that speed is constant. If so, you can move obstacle to the player this way:

```
private void _Update()
    {
        var characterPosition = //cant say what it should be in your case
        MoveTo(characterPosition);
    }

    private void MoveTo(Vector3 target)
    {
        //use 'transform' if you`re moving the obstacle from the script that is attached to it
        //if your moving it from some scene controller or anywhere else, call [Obstacle].transform
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

In this code Speed value should be available in both methods - the one that moves the obstacle and the one that instantiates it. You can make Speed constant or put it in some global config script for example.
And in Spawn() method you can calculate correct distance:

```
{
   var timeToFall = 2f;//amount of time that the obstacle will fall
   var position = new Vector3(0, timeToFall * Speed, 0);
}
```

Comment: Does this matter, as I'm using an InvokeRepeating?

Comment: As far as I remember, Invoke and InvokeRepeating methods are processed by the background thread and Time.deltaTime (just as many other engine methods and properties) can be used in the main thread only.

Comment: I see. I read your updated answer. Could you come with a suggestion making this time dependant? I've tried messing around with it, but without results.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I think you misunderstood my question. My issue is not the spawn interval, my issue is the movement interval, from where the obstacle spawns until it hits my player. I added a picture for context.

Comment: @PhilMcLaren - just FYI there are absolutely no threads in Unity; it is very strictly a single-threaded thing.  you are completely correct that Time.deltaTime can of course only be used in Update(); the OPs code is completely wrong.  (but it has no connection to threads, FYI)

Answer (score 0):

`Time.deltaTime` stores time differences between frames. The use of `Time.deltaTime` will only make sense if you use it on Update method, which is called every frame.

In your case, you can calculate time elapsed between each `Spawn()` call. Store current `Time.time` in a property, and calculate the difference between last `Spawn` execution:

```
float lastUpdate = 0;    

void Spawn() {
    float myDelta = Time.time - lastTime;
    lastUpdate = Time.time
```

Then replace use of `Time.deltaTime` with `myDelta` variable:

```
float lastUpdate = 0;    

void Spawn() {
    float myDelta = Time.time - lastTime;
    lastUpdate = Time.time

    if (pScript.isRight == true && pScript.inAir == false) {
        obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1);
        Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3 (0.05F, (4F + pScript.playerDimensionY + oScript.obstacleDimensionY) * myDelta, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    } else if (pScript.isRight == false && pScript.inAir == false) {
        obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
        Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3 (-0.05F, (4F + pScript.playerDimensionY + oScript.obstacleDimensionY) * myDelta, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```